# Как найти и выбрать элементы коллекции,используя методы map и search?

Tags: php, laravel, коллекции, eloquent

Получена коллекция с помощью модели eloquent:

```
$posts= Post::where(‘confirm’,’1’)->get();
```

Как выбрать из неё все записи, в которых присутствует слово ‘брюки´?

```
$posts=$posts->search(‘брюки’)
```

возвращает false и потом согласно документации этот способ может вернуть только один элемент, а нужны все записи.

Comment: Вероятно `filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если предположить, что свойство модели `Post`, в котором нужно искать совпадения, называется `text` и вы по каким-либо причинам не хотите произвести фильтрацию на уровне запроса к БД таким образом:

```
 $posts = Post::where('confirm', '1')->where('text', 'LIKE', '%брюки%')->get();
```

то выбрать записи из коллекции можно следующим образом:

```
$posts = $posts->filter(function ($post) {
    return mb_stripos($post['text'], 'брюки') !== false;
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-filter